# Delete lines with same fields/strings

Tags: awk, sed

I rewrite my previous question because it was unclear.
I have *test1.txt* formatted in this way (this example has 3 lines)

```
Link;alfa (zz);some text;
Link;alfa (zz);other text;other text2;
Link;jack;
```

In another filetext *test2.txt* I have text formatted in this way without delimiters `;` but only as simple string (this example has 2 lines)

```
tommy emmanuel
alfa (zz)
```

In `test2.txt` I have never `Link` word and I can I have `(` `)` characters but I have never `;` delimiter character

I want to get *result.txt* written in this way

```
Link;jack;
```

**Logic behind** : In *test2.txt* I have `alfa (zz)`. This string / field is the same in *test1.txt* - I have the *same* string `alfa (zz)` on first and second line between`;` delimiter. **Condition**: if this field match happens then that lines should be deleted and for this reason I written that I expect only 3rd line

```
Link;jack;
```

I test this code

```
sed 's/.*Link;//;s/;.*//' test2.txt | grep -Fvf- test1.txt
```

and this

```
awk -F \; '
FNR == NR {cull[$0]=""}
FNR != NR {
    for (str in cull) {
        if ($2 == str) {
            next
        }
    }
    print
}' test2.txt test1.txt > culled.txt
```

Problem is that it rewrite me same lines and don't delete lines with same fields

**Update question**:

According to anubhava answer and [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/JRQD9m5L) example the presence of this kind of strings don't remove lines

If I have inside test2.txt

```
Dark Tranquillity - A Moonclad Reflection [ep] (1992) Melodic Death Metal
Dark Tranquillity - A Closer End [best of_compilation] (2008) Melodic Death Metal
```

then I can't match and remove lines in text1.txt if I have these lines

```
Link;Dark Tranquillity - A Moonclad Reflection [ep] (1992) Melodic Death Metal;Dark Tranquillity - A moonclad reflection [7'' Ep 1992_Slaughter Rec.].rar;https://disk.yandex.com/public?hash=JA7Gu2CysxSf2HhAKaBxmU%2By27B6dPd6uRwPFu%2B9x0s%3D;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=5037

Link;Dark Tranquillity - A Closer End [best of_compilation] (2008) Melodic Death Metal;Dark Tranquillity - A Closer End [2008].rar;https://disk.yandex.com/public?hash=RCZbOrqci8lX%2Fa%2BPzhB6vchlr5rXyc%2B2NHiJNCu%2BQYM%3D;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=48557
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem - with the sample snippets the awk script does the right thing.

Comment: After latest edits and the data samples provided by OP it is clear that none of the original commands will work to solve the problem. Easily reproducible.

Comment: Please read [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) to learn what's almost certainly causing your problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F';' 'FNR == NR {
   gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/, "")
   cull[$0]
   next
}
!($2 in cull)' test2.txt test1.txt > culled.txt

cat culled.txt

Link;Dark Tranquillity - Enter Suicidal Angels [ep] (1996) Melodic Death Metal;Dark Tranquillity 1996 - Enter Suicidal Angels (EP).rar;https://disk.yandex.com/public?hash=fBvwBTBJ8%2Fx1mWXvl7usrAMe06esHZFDmHJWF8E2T6LK7Wvfu9Q5Qja9cb5JAU%2Fzq%2FJ6bpmRyOJonT3VoXnDag%3D%3D;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=5041
Link;Sea Of Tranquillity - Darkened [demo] (1993) Death_Thrash Metal;eaofT3Dd.7z;https://disk.yandex.com/public?hash=DzCNqfEv2pydYzB0YWVvetV2Jx8QDCwktop3y8PIC%2BD5W%2Fnt8ikX81%2F7cf49g8dNq%2FJ6bpmRyOJonT3VoXnDag%3D%3D;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=153504
Link;Dark Tranquillity - The Absolute [single] (2017) Melodic Death Metal (D);Dark Tranquillity - The Absolute (2017) Single MCD (+SATANIST666+).rar;https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ckFc/A5sQ6pqhb;
Link;Dark Tranquillity - Trail Of Life Decayed [ep] (1992) Melodic Death Metal;1991 - Trail Of Life Decayed.7z;https://www.mediafire.com/file/5pi74bqvujea9rg/1991_-_Trail_Of_Life_Decayed.7z/file;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=5115
Link;Dark Tranquillity - Phantom Days [single] (2020) Melodic Death Metal (D);Dark Tranquillity - Phantom Days (2020) by Andrew.rar;https://www.mediafire.com/file/ho25i02j3ybgmty/Dark_Tranquillity_-_Phantom_Days_%25282020%2529_by_Andrew.rar/file;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=341548
Link;Dark Tranquillity - Of Chaos And Eternal Night [ep] (1995) Melodic Death Metal;Dark Tranquillity - Of Chaos And Eternal Night (EP) [1995].rar;https://disk.yandex.com/public?hash=Ax%2B2Gfqzr9%2FdS87cgRcUhGBCoQzKZfz5ZDUa2U%2Fbsn4%3D;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=5040
Link;Dark Tranquillity - Of Chaos And Eternal Night [ep] (1995) Melodic Death Metal;Dark Tranquillity 1995 - Of Chaos And Eternal Night (EP).rar;https://disk.yandex.com/public?hash=le8r7ZI%2F%2BTw2CjsDbNFriDZdCGpSy1hj%2BoQdGHrrBFdcJM8eIp%2F3J17qG5MjC1Fgq%2FJ6bpmRyOJonT3VoXnDag%3D%3D;https://metalarea.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=5040
```

There is no need to use `for` loop. Just create an associative array while reading content from 2nd file and then while reading 1st file print only line that have 2nd column not in array `seen`.

Comment: I test your script but it failed in this condition, please look [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/JRQD9m5L) - for example if I have in test1.txt only 2 lines and contains is `Dark Tranquillity - A Moonclad Reflection [ep] (1992) Melodic Death Metal` from test2.txt then your script removes that line but not if there are more of some number of lines, I don't understand why

Comment: Well ... that will be because e.g. `Dark Tranquillity - Enter Suicidal Angels [ep] (1996), Melodic Death Metal` and
`Dark Tranquillity - Enter Suicidal Angels [ep] (1996) Melodic Death Metal` aren't identical ... notice the `,` in the former?

Comment: mm..sorry, I didn't see `,` character but if you test you can still see that it doesn't remove lines with `Dark Tranquillity - A Moonclad Reflection [ep] (1992) Melodic Death Metal`
and `Dark Tranquillity - A Closer End [best of_compilation] (2008) Melodic Death Metal` inside *test1.txt*

Comment: @anubhava ok, I update question with these examples

Comment: @JackRock: It seems you have trailing spaces in your `test2` file. I have added `gsub` call in my code to address this.

Comment: @anubhava I test again but it fails. Please take a look of [my short video](https://mega.nz/file/lwZ0xJyL#eK2jl1PjZqi69VNght8l14ZEG3nlRMnm2P4wz2b41JQ) where I show you how your solution fails. Mm.. I don't sure that problem is only trailing spaces

Comment: @anubhava sorry, **four** lines are not removed in culled.txt. As source for test1 and test2 I used [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/JRQD9m5L) example. I also test in linux ubuntu terminal but return me same problem, is not a cygwin error

Comment: The OP almost certainly has DOS line endings (or some other white space that's not included in `[[:blank:]]`) in test2.txt and CR isn't included in `[[:blank:]]`. This is one of the reasons I always use `[[:space:]]` instead of `[[:blank:]]` unless I specifically NEED to exclude some of the white space characters like CR.

Comment: @EdMorton your `[[:blank:]]` to `[[:space:]]` replacement solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: @JackRock good, I updated this answer with that change.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you so much for your suggestion of DOS line break and your edit of my answer to make it a working solution. Jack: Thanks for edits in question and good sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/^/cat file2/e;x};G;/^Link;([^;]*);.*\n\1(\n|$)/!P;d' file1
```

Gather up file2 in the hold space.

Append the hold space to each line in file1 and if there is match between the second field of file1 and any field in file2, delete the line.

Otherwise print the first line in the pattern space i.e. the current line in file1.

Comment: mm.. I don't understand well your solution, it seems doesn't work because it returns same lines.., I replaced `file2.t/e;x}` and `file1` with `test2.txt.t/e;x}` and `test2.txt`